# R join two data frames, group by column and calculate mean

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate, mean

I've Googled around, but I can't seem to find a solution for the problem I'm having. I have two data frames, one holds movies by ID and contains ratings for them:

```
> summary(ratings)
    movieId        mean_rating      rating_count    
 Min.   :     1   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   :    1.0  
 1st Qu.:  6796   1st Qu.: 5.600   1st Qu.:    3.0  
 Median : 65880   Median : 6.471   Median :   18.0  
 Mean   : 58790   Mean   : 6.266   Mean   :  747.8  
 3rd Qu.: 99110   3rd Qu.: 7.130   3rd Qu.:  205.0  
 Max.   :131262   Max.   :10.000   Max.   :67310.0  
      rn           
 Length:26744      
 Class :character  
 Mode  :character
```

The other one is a collection of user defined tags that have been added to these movies. It also has a column called `movieId` that corresponds to `movieId` in the first data frame.

```
> summary(tags)
     userId          movieId           tag           
 Min.   :    18   Min.   :     1   Length:465564     
 1st Qu.: 28780   1st Qu.:  2571   Class :character  
 Median : 70201   Median :  7373   Mode  :character  
 Mean   : 68712   Mean   : 32628                     
 3rd Qu.:107322   3rd Qu.: 62235                     
 Max.   :138472   Max.   :131258                     
   timestamp               rn           
 Min.   :1135429210   Length:465564     
 1st Qu.:1245007262   Class :character  
 Median :1302291181   Mode  :character  
 Mean   :1298711076                     
 3rd Qu.:1366217861                     
 Max.   :1427771352
```

What I want to do, is get the mean movie rating for each of the tags. Basically, the equivalent of this SQL query:

```
SELECT t.tag, AVG(r.mean_rating) FROM movielens_tags t RIGHT JOIN movielens_ratings r ON t.movieId = r.movieId GROUP BY t.tag;
```

I just need 2 columns in the output:

```
      tag      mean_rating
sci_fi         6.23
bollywood      7.45
action         5.75
```

However, this SQL query will never end. That's why I want to do it in R. Can anyone help me on how I should approach this?

Comment: Please add reproducible example and add the expected output.

Comment: @Sotos Added the expected output! A reproducible sample is quite hard as that's exactly what my problem is. My query never ends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the `dplyr` translation of your SQL code (package `dplyr` should be installed):

```
library(dplyr)

movielens_tags %>%
  right_join(movielens_ratings, by = "movieId") %>%
  group_by(tag) %>%
  summarise(mean_rating = mean(mean_rating)
```